# I get Parser.parseErrorMessage when inserting or updating in postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

i'm having a headache with this cause i can't understand what's the problem.

This is my code in Express

```
router.patch("/:id", verifyToken, async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const { title, content, categories } = req.body;
  const authorId = parseInt(req.user.id);

  try {
    let postId = parseInt(id);
    
    if (postId < 0)
      res.json(
        utils.generateError("Something went wrong, try to reload the page.")
      );

    //Validate post data
    const { error } = validatePostData({
      title,
      content,
    });

    //Is there and error? Let the user know it.
    if (error)
      res.status(400).json(utils.generateError(error.details[0].message));

    const slug = await utils.generateSlug(title);
    const summary = await utils.extractSummary(content, 240);
    const foundImage = await content.match(/!\[.*?\]\((.*?)\)/);
    let image = "";
    if (foundImage) image = foundImage[1];

    const result = await pool.query(
      "UPDATE posts SET title=$1, slug=$2, summary=$3, content=$4, image=$5, author=$6, categories=$7 WHERE id=$8",
      [title, slug, summary, content, image, authorId, categories, postId]
    );

    if (result) res.json(result.rows[0]);
    else throw "Error on updating result";
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.json(utils.generateError("Something went wrong, try again."));
  }
});
```

But when i make a patch request i get this in the console.

```
(node:20756) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: invalid input syntax for integer: "NaN"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/Users/jcmunguia/Desktop/readalot-app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:278:15)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/Users/jcmunguia/Desktop/readalot-app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/jcmunguia/Desktop/readalot-app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/jcmunguia/Desktop/readalot-app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:8:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:286:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:268:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)
(node:20756) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:20756) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm using Postgres and pg for node to handle the database, the strange part is that the row is updated in the db but the result of the query doesn't return anything but that error.

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: I'm not adding an answer, but I think you will get a more minimal view of what the error is? if you catch your `pool.query`. i.e. `pool.query('wahteverquery').then(response){return response}.catch(err){return err}`

Comment: Thanks for answering, unfortunately i'm still getting the same error.. nothing new.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm having the exact same problem